# What happens to the current view controller when you go back to the previous view controller?

Tags: ios

This might seem to be a dumb question but I am not quite sure with what happens. Does the current view controller gets destroyed and any activity would stop? Or it gets preserved so that the same content does not have to be reloaded later?

Comment: If there are no strong references, then yes it would be deinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

It must deinitialized. The simple way to see it happens is to add deinit function to your ViewController.

```
 deinit {
    print("Deinited " + self.className)
}
```